# Почему тут нет запятых?

Tags: другое

Сегодня проходили устойчивые сочетания. Вот два из них, например: ни то ни се,  ни рыба ни мясо. Мне интересно, почему в таких сочетаниях нет запятой? Понимаю, что это устойчивые, одна мне непонятно, как они становятся устойчивыми.

Будьте любезны объяснить =)

Comment: Тагир, вам когда говорят: Будьте любезны объяснить", это означает, что вы чем-то провинились и от вас ждут оправдательных доводов по поводу вашего проступка (смайлик).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устойчивые сочетания, значит, они устоялись, то есть, повторясь многократно в этом виде, стали воспроизводиться людьми неизменно. К примеру, "ни рыба ни мясо" - это устойчивое выражение, оно воспроизводится людьми в таком, неизменном виде, а вот сочетание "ни рыба, ни холодец" - это не устойчивое сочетание, и здесь нужна запятая

Comment: Интересно, если поставить запятую, то это уже будет ошибкой? ;)

Comment: Да, будет ошибка

Comment: Очень благодарен.

Comment: Можете кликнуть: "Принять ответ"

Answer (score 2):

В некоторых случаях при тесном смысловом единстве двух однородных членов с союзами И…И, НИ…НИ  запятая между ними не ставится, что особенно характерно для синонимов, антонимов и фразеологизмов: ни конца ни края (синонимы), и в жар и в холод, и день и ночь (антонимы), и в огонь и в воду, ни свет ни заря (фразеологизмы).

Также возможно сближение признаков, описывающих одну ситуацию: В шатре и тихо и темно. Были и лето и осень дождливы.

Устойчивость фразы можно определить на слух:нет паузы и перечислительной интонации, этим подчеркивается единство выражения, его повышенная значимость. Например: Здесь ни проехать ни пройти - вообще нельзя пробраться, усилительная частица НИ в составе союза.

Если однородные члены не образуют цельного сочетания, то запятая  между ними ставится,  интонация перечислительная: Это касается и меня, и вас. Я один у окошка, ни гостя, ни друга не жду.